# CVPixelBuffer vs. CVImageBuffer, and Buffers in general

Tags: swift, core-image, core-video

What's the difference between [CVImageBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvimagebuffer-q40) which is returned by `CMSampleBufferGetmageBuffer` and [CVPixelBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvpixelbuffer-q2e)? I just want to retrieve the image planes (RGBA) but I can't figure out how to retrieve this information from CVImageBuffer. I'm using Swift.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

They are identical in swift. If you look at the definition underneath, you will see this:

```
public typealias CVPixelBuffer = CVImageBuffer
```

which means that you can use you can use the methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvpixelbuffer-q2e) if you want to find the image planes(I don't know what that means exactly). But CVPixelBuffer is a concrete implementation of the abstract class CVImageBuffer. There are two types of CVImageBuffers in use at the moment-CVPixelBuffers and OpenGLBuffers. You can choose to break the abstraction if you know for certain that your CVImageBuffer is a CVPixelBuffer.